About max and min of bounded signed measure

If $\mu$ is a bounded signed measure on a measurable space $(\mathcal{F}, \Omega)$, then there exist $A_1, A_2$ in the space satisfying the following:
$$
\mu(A_1) = \max \{\mu(A)\}, \\
\mu(A_2) = \min \{\mu(A)\}
$$
where $A$ runs through $\Omega$.

I really cannot think of how to start this so I cannot write any attempt here. Can you give a hint on how to construct such $A_1$ and $A_2$?

Perhaps the Hahn decomposition theorem is a good starting point, then the claim simply follows from $\mu(A)\leq\mu(B)$ for every measurable $A\subset B$, with a slight adaption of course to account for the fact that signed measures can be negative. Can you finish?
